# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet in heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku, badsqlgrammarexception

Good day.
I have application which deploied on Heroku.
Application wrote on spring boot. It works fine in local.It works fine in Heroku if i enter (admin, password which was insert in liquebase). I can open pages in heroku with migrated data. But if i want to create new user or new topic( like insert in DB) i recieve  org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet. I dont have any idea and understanding how to fix it. Could you help me?
I use PostrgeSQL ,Spring boot

scripts for liquebase
schema.sql

```
 CREATE TABLE usr
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  active boolean NOT NULL,
  email character varying(255),
  first_name character varying(255),
  last_name character varying(255),
  password character varying(255),
  username character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT usr_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_role
(
  user_id bigint NOT NULL,
  roles character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_role_us FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES usr (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE topic
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  content character varying(255),
  created timestamp without time zone,
  name character varying(255),
  user_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT topic_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_topic FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES usr (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE comments
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  text character varying(255),
  user_id bigint,
  topic_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT comments_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_comments_us FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES usr (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_comments_to FOREIGN KEY (topic_id)
      REFERENCES topic (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

script for insert.sql

```
insert into usr values (1,TRUE,'mrArxi@gmail.com','Vladimir','Vladimir','12345','Rustymattok');
insert into user_role values (1,'ADMIN');
insert into topic values (1,'smth','2016-06-22 19:10:25-07','Vladimir',1);
insert into comments values (1,'spring boot help',1,1);
```

application.properties

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
# boot
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
# data base jpa
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/4job
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/forum}
spring.datasource.username=${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME:postgres}
spring.datasource.password=${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD :admin}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

heroku.properties

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
# boot
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
## datasource
spring.datasource.url=postgres://xvgbbyabcnxrwh:ea21081dc20d1e648812718125bef4aa603ea60e63b13ffb06cd2a23acf90344@ec2-54-247-122-209.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/db8l3sl1gpm7i4
server.port=${PORT:5000}
```

Procfile

```
web: java -jar target/4jobforum-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.config.location=heroku.properties
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>4jobforum</groupId>
    <artifactId>4jobforum</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!--<spring.profiles.active>local,no-liquibase</spring.profiles.active>-->
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--DataBase support-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
```

log file during deploy

```
2020-08-02T17:11:02.566933+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2020-08-02T17:11:06.129619+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -jar target/4jobforum-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.config.location=heroku.properties`
2020-08-02T17:11:07.881906+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2020-08-02T17:11:07.885202+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2020-08-02T17:11:09.549537+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:09.544  INFO 4 --- [           main] ru.makarov.SpringWebApplication          : Starting SpringWebApplication v1.0-SNAPSHOT on 74a1432b-9c2b-4216-ac90-7ba17e0c0929 with PID 4 (/app/target/4jobforum-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar started by u56548 in /app)
2020-08-02T17:11:09.550740+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:09.550  INFO 4 --- [           main] ru.makarov.SpringWebApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-08-02T17:11:10.743828+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:10.741  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-08-02T17:11:10.868091+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:10.867  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 110ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-08-02T17:11:11.509192+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:11.508  INFO 4 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-08-02T17:11:11.545270+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:11.545  INFO 4 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-08-02T17:11:11.549013+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:11.548  INFO 4 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-08-02T17:11:11.551743+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:11.551  INFO 4 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@14dd9eb7' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-08-02T17:11:11.552900+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:11.552  INFO 4 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-08-02T17:11:11.557767+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:11.557  INFO 4 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-08-02T17:11:11.990844+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:11.990  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 21495 (http)
2020-08-02T17:11:12.007032+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:12.006  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-08-02T17:11:12.007293+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:12.007  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29]
2020-08-02T17:11:12.539887+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:12.539  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2020-08-02T17:11:12.811533+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:12.811  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-08-02T17:11:12.811759+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:12.811  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3158 ms
2020-08-02T17:11:13.177663+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:13.177  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-08-02T17:11:13.498474+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:13.498  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-08-02T17:11:14.384825+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:14.384  INFO 4 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.databasechangeloglock
2020-08-02T17:11:14.386931+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:14.386  INFO 4 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.databasechangeloglock
2020-08-02T17:11:14.389837+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:14.389  INFO 4 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT LOCKED FROM public.databasechangeloglock WHERE ID=1
2020-08-02T17:11:14.408959+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:14.408  INFO 4 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully acquired change log lock
2020-08-02T17:11:15.283976+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:15.283  INFO 4 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT MD5SUM FROM public.databasechangelog WHERE MD5SUM IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1
2020-08-02T17:11:15.285842+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:15.285  INFO 4 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.databasechangelog
2020-08-02T17:11:15.287163+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:15.287  INFO 4 --- [           main] l.c.StandardChangeLogHistoryService      : Reading from public.databasechangelog
2020-08-02T17:11:15.287451+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:15.287  INFO 4 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT * FROM public.databasechangelog ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC
2020-08-02T17:11:15.301421+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:15.301  INFO 4 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully released change log lock
2020-08-02T17:11:15.431032+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:15.430  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-08-02T17:11:15.562816+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:15.562  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.9.Final}
2020-08-02T17:11:15.771354+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:15.771  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-08-02T17:11:15.935060+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:15.934  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2020-08-02T17:11:17.179767+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:17.179  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-08-02T17:11:17.189142+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:17.188  INFO 4 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-08-02T17:11:17.258418+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:17.258  WARN 4 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-08-02T17:11:18.110334+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:18.110  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@65e61854, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@1ca25c47, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@79e18e38, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@71e5f61d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5b6813df, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@1e5f4170, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@533b266e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@89ff02e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1568159, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1849db1a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@60fa3495, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2b62442c]
2020-08-02T17:11:18.302424+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:18.302  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-08-02T17:11:18.452889+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:18.452  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2020-08-02T17:11:18.675452+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:18.675  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 21495 (http) with context path ''
2020-08-02T17:11:18.680000+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:18.679  INFO 4 --- [           main] ru.makarov.SpringWebApplication          : Started SpringWebApplication in 9.946 seconds (JVM running for 10.795)
2020-08-02T17:11:19.075009+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-08-02T17:11:19.973115+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:19.972  INFO 4 --- [io-21495-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-08-02T17:11:19.973286+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:19.973  INFO 4 --- [io-21495-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-08-02T17:11:19.982684+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-02 17:11:19.982  INFO 4 --- [io-21495-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 9 ms
```

log file during status 500

```
2020-08-02T17:14:03.307295+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/newtopic" host=forum-4job.herokuapp.com request_id=aabbf4a0-05a3-4eb7-8692-a7a29bd8d52f fwd="176.120.239.23" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=99ms status=500 bytes=835 protocol=https
```

Entinity

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Topic {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @NonNull
    private String name;
    @NonNull
    private String content;
    @NonNull
    private Calendar created;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User author;
```

Controller

```
 @PostMapping("/newtopic")
    public String createTopic(@ModelAttribute("topic") Topic topic) {
        Calendar currentTime = new GregorianCalendar();
        topic.setCreated(currentTime);
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userStore.findUserByUsername(auth.getName());
        topic.setAuthor(userStore.findUserById(user.getId()));
        topicStore.save(topic);
        return "redirect:/index";
    }
```

UserService crude

```
@Repository
public interface UserServiceCrud extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findUserByUsername(String username);

    User findUserById(Long id);
}
```

TopicService Crude

```
@Repository
public interface TopicServiceCrud extends JpaRepository<Topic, Long> {
    Topic findAllById(Long id);

    List<Topic> findAllByAuthor(User user);
}
```

Comment: You need to include the log part with the information about the error and the code you are using to deal with database

Comment: added upper more info. There are no logs... all is fine instead status 500. And this error only on heroku. In local all is fine. My suggestion smth is wrong in heroku DB properties

Answer (score 1):

The reasone in scripts of schema.sql and insert.
For Heroku you should use id auto creation SERIAL.
For Models ID generation strategy  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

Samples below

schema.sql

```
CREATE TABLE usr
(
  id SERIAL primary key,
  active boolean NOT NULL,
  email character varying(255),
  first_name character varying(255),
  last_name character varying(255),
  password character varying(255),
  username character varying(255)
);
CREATE TABLE user_role
(
  user_id SERIAL,
  roles character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_role_us FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES usr (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
CREATE TABLE topic
(
  id SERIAL primary key,
  content character varying(255),
  created timestamp without time zone,
  name character varying(255),
  user_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT fk_topic FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES usr (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
CREATE TABLE comments
(
  id SERIAL primary key,
  text character varying(255),
  user_id bigint,
  topic_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT fk_comments_us FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES usr (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_comments_to FOREIGN KEY (topic_id)
      REFERENCES topic (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

insert.sql

```
insert into usr (active, email, first_name, last_name, password, username) values (TRUE,'mrArxi@gmail.com','Vladimir','Vladimir','12345','Rustymattok');
insert into user_role(user_id,roles) values((select id from usr where username = 'Rustymattok'), 'ADMIN');
insert into topic(content,created,name,user_id) values ('smth','2016-06-22 19:10:25-07','Vladimir test',(select id from usr where username = 'Rustymattok'));
insert into comments(text,user_id,topic_id) values ('spring boot help',(select id from usr where username = 'Rustymattok'),(select id from topic where name = 'Vladimir test'));
```

sample of Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NonNull
    private String password;
    @NonNull
    private String username;
    @NonNull
    private String firstName;
    @NonNull
    private String lastName;
    @NonNull
    private String email;
    @NonNull
    private boolean active;
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;
```